# Print to POS Printer does not return to start position

Tags: c#, printing, pos

I have a EPSON TM L60 II and i print to the printer using this code:

I do this in C# using a library to 
"\x0C Line 1 Line 2 Line 3\x0A\x0A")

This will give me a paper feed, the text and then 2 line feeds (so i can cut off the label). But the next print needs to put back the lable a little, but it does not do that automatically. Someone know about a function for this? If i dont do it there will always be one empty lable between 2 prints because of the printer not taking back the lable a little.

Thanks,

Joey

Answer (score 1):

Epson label printers like the TM L60 II have a "[black mark control function](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=44)" `FS ( L` which is designed exactly for this purpose, and are a lot more accurate than new lines.

I don't have a label printer or C# to show a working example, but I'll quote this PHP example that was contributed to the issue tracker of a driver that I contribute to. Hopefully you can adapt it:

```
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->getPrintConnector()->write(Printer::FS."(L".chr(2).chr(0).chr(65).chr(49));
```